# boto3 get_resources paginator doesn't work with within console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, tagging

I'm attempting to use get_resources from the resourcesgrouptaggingAPI and paginate it. I'm doing this with a lambda function and boto3.

However, using `base = client.can_paginate('get_resources')` returns `False` although within the [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#paginators) it suggests that it works for `get_resources`.

Another person had this problem and created an issue of it [here.](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1218)  Now It seems to work for him, so I am trying to investigate what would cause the console lambda environment to not work.

Just for clarity is here is my declaration and initialization:

```
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
base = client.can_paginate('get_resources') #returns False
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_resources')
```

Thus, is there a problem with using the console for pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS lambda environment isn't always running the most up to date version of boto3/botocore. It currently offers botocore version `1.5.52` (source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html ). The paginator you're trying to access was released in 1.5.53 (source: https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/144dda7b63f9eccaeae66c040a281208b43e2678 )

As such you're attempting to use a version of botocore where pagination of `get_resources` isn't yet supported. In this case you need to bundle a version of boto3/botocore which supports that functionality with your lambda by installing before bundling.

E.g. if your source code was in the directory src:

`pip install boto3==1.4.4
cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* src/
cd src
zip -rq lambda.zip .`

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but the confirmation and solution really helps. Thanks!